# Existence of minimum for $\inf_{k \in \mathbb{R}} E[|X-k|^p]$

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, approximation-theory

Suppose $E[|X|^p ]< \infty$ for the given $p \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$.

How to show that the following expression has a minimum
\begin{align}
\inf_{k \in \mathbb{R}} E[|X-k|^p]
\end{align}

That is $\inf_{k \in \mathbb{R}} E[|X-k|^p]=\min_{k \in \mathbb{R}} E[|X-k|^p]$ and the minimizing $k$ exists. Observe, that I am not looking for what $k$ is just that it exists. However, knowing what $k$ is a plus.

Clearly the infimum exists since 
\begin{align}
0 \le \inf_{k \in \mathbb{R}} E[|X-k|^p] \le E[|X-0|^p]=E[|X|^p] < \infty
\end{align}

Here is my solution for when $p$ is an even integer

\begin{align}
\inf_{k \in \mathbb{R}} E[|X-k|^p]&=\inf_{k \in \mathbb{R}} E[(X-k)^p] \text{ used the fact that $p$ is even}\\
&= \inf_{k \in \mathbb{R}} E \left[ \sum_{n=0}^p { p \choose n} X^{p-n}k^{n}  \right] \text{ Binomial formula}\\
&=\inf_{k \in \mathbb{R}} \sum_{n=0}^p { p \choose n}  E\left[ X^{p-n} \right] k^{n}  
\end{align}
where the expectation $E\left[ X^{p-k} \right]$ exists since $E\left[ |X|^{p} \right]$ exist.

Now the $\inf_{k \in \mathbb{R}} \sum_{n=0}^p { p \choose n}  E\left[ X^{p-n} \right] k^{n}$ is a polynomial of an even degree and therefore has a minimum. 
So, for $p$ even 
\begin{align}
\inf_{k \in \mathbb{R}} \sum_{n=0}^p { p \choose n}  E\left[ X^{p-n} \right] k^{n}=\min_{k \in \mathbb{R}} \sum_{n=0}^p { p \choose n}  E\left[ X^{p-n} \right] k^{n}
\end{align}

and there exist a minimizing $k$.

**My question is** how to extend this proof to any real $k>0$.

Thank you looking forward to you input.

**Edit**

Based on the  discussion in the comments:
We have been able to show that for $p \ge 1$ the function $f(y)=E[|X-y|^p]$ is **continuous.**   This is done by using dominated convergence theorem.

Another, property we have been able to show is that if $y_n$ is such that 
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty} E[(X-y_n)^p]=\inf_{y}E[|X-y|^p]
\end{align}
then $y_n$ **is bounded.**

However, I am still not sure how this implies that there exists $y_0$ that minimizes  $f(y)=E[|X-y|^p]$? Please help.

Comment: $E|X-k|^p$ is convex, bounded from below and goes to $\infty$ for $|k|\to\infty$ ...

Comment: This implies that infimum exists, right? Does it implies that minimizing $k$ exists?

Comment: That also implies the existence of a minimizer

Comment: Do convex functions bounded from below attain the minimum? Is this something very simple?

Comment: No, the important point is, that the function value tends to $\infty$ for $|k|\to\infty$

Comment: @user251257 Could you elaborate more please? I am drawing a blank.  Thank you

Comment: Let $k_n$ such that $E|X-k_n|^p$ tends to the infimum. Could $k_n$ be unbounded? If not, what happens?

Comment: Ok. I think I start to understand. If $k_n$ is such that $E[|X-k_n|^p]$ tends to infimum then sequence $\{k_n \}$ must be bounded, other wise   $E[|X-k_n|^p]$ is unbounded which is a contradiction.  So, next we have to show that that $k_n$ converges to $k$ which is a minimum, right?

Comment: Sorry, for so many questions.  I am just trying to understand this in as much detail as I can

Comment: @Boby: A bounded sequence contains a subsequence which converges. You just have to show that the limit is a minimum.

Comment: @PhoemueX  So, do I have to use convexity for that somehow?

Comment: @Boby: That is one possibility, since convex functions (defined on an open set) are continuous. But you could also show directly that $y\mapsto E|X-y|^p $ is continuous.

Comment: @PhoemueX So use. like dominated convergence theorem or MCT?

Comment: That function is *not* necessarily convex. But it does diverge to infinity as $k\to\pm\infty$. So in view of continuity, it attains minimum.

Comment: Ok. I am lost, when can it be non-convex?

Comment: The question is, why it *is* convex. For $p\ge 1$ this is thanks to Jensen's inequality. For $p<1$ this may fail (take e.g. a constant $X\equiv c$).

Comment: @zhoraster You, right. I had in mind that $p \ge 1$.  So, how do I show continuity with out invoking convexity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collected from the comments.

**Fact 1.** $f(y) = E[|X-y|^p]$ is continuous. Indeed, for any sequence $\{y_n,n\ge 1\}$ such that $y_n\to y_0$, $n\to\infty$, we have $f(y_n)\to f(y_0)$ in view of the dominated convergence theorem (thanks to convergence, $\{|y_n|\}$ is bounded by some $k$).

**Fact 2.** $f\to+\infty$, $f\to\pm\infty$. Hint: use the Fatou lemma. Therefore, there exists some $R$ such that $f(y) > f(0)$ whenever $|y|>R$. Thus, $\inf_{y\in\mathbb{R}} f(y) = \inf_{|y|\le R} f(y) = \min_{|y|\le R} f(y)$ thanks to continuity.

From these two facts the existence of minimum follows.

Comment: So, here is my attempt to show Fact 1. We have  to show that  $y \to E[|X-y|^p]$ is continuous.  The ideas it to use Dominated Convergence Theorem (DCT).    To use DCT we must show that $|X-y|^p \le Z$ for every $y$ by some $Z$. We have that $|X-y|^p \le 2^p|X|^p+2^p|y|^p$.  Can I assume that $|y|$ is bounded by some $k$, here? And take $Z=2^p|X|^p+2^p k^p$.

Comment: Here is my attempt to prove that min exists. Suppose $y_n$ is a sequence that tends to infimum that is $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(y_n)= \inf_{y}f(y)$. We also know that $y_n$ must be bounded otherwise $f(y)=\infty$. Now I am stuck, how do we show that $y_n$ converges to minimum $y_0$ and that it exists? Use continuity somehow? Also, I know that Fatou's lemma says $\inf_y E[|X-y|^p] \ge E[\inf_y |X-y|^p]$ but how to use it?

Comment: Ok. Maybe in terms of liminf $E[ \liminf_{k \to \infty} |X-y_k|^p] \le \liminf_{k \to \infty} E[  |X-y_k|^p]$

Comment: We get infinity on the left hand side. Implying that $y_n$ must be bounded, right?

Comment: So, let me summarize. Up to now we have that $f(y)=E[|X-y|^p]$ is continuos, also if $y_n$ is such that $\liminf_{n \to \infty} E[|X-y_n|^p]= \inf_{y}E[|X-y|^p$ then $y_n$ must be bounded.  So, the trick is now to show that $y_n$ converges, right?

Comment: @Boby, it does not need to converge. But you can extract a convergent subsequence.

Comment: So, $y_{n_k} \to y_0$ is a convergent subsequence of $y_n$ then by continuity of $f$ we have that $\lim_{n\to \infty}E[|X-y_n|^p]=E[|X-y_0|^p] \ge \inf_{y}E[|X-y|^p]$. So, we have to show the revers inequality?